# Websocket NodeJS Crashing

Tags: node.js, websocket

Hey there im getting this error which is crashing my program after 12h or 24h and i have to restart it is there anyway to fix this?

ERROR :

```
/root/Chat/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:334
      throw new Error('WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)');
      ^

Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)
    at WebSocket.send (/root/Chat/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:334:13)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/root/Chat/index.js:51:14)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

Code : https://hastebin.com/fayasobeha.js

Comment: can you show your code here

Comment: @PiyushDubey I posted it on hastebin as it's kind large so idk if i should post it here

Comment: Post the code which is a minimal reproduction of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets are not a common TCP servers, They are more of 2 way connection between the Client and the Server. If you following any architecture(Micro/Mono) Make sure you check is there any other system thread going on at peak hours which is causing the crash.
It's always better if you can wrap your service in Container and run it as a separate process there.